# Can someone tell me why this else statement is giving me a syntax error in Python

Tags: python

I know this question has been asked before, but they do not seem to be working for me. I would like if someone could tell me why this `else` statement has been giving me a syntax error.

EDIT: Sorry, I have pasted in the whole code now, and what error I am getting. Sorry about being vague or inconsistent in my question.

```python
from sys import argv
from sys import exit
from time import *
from random import *
import os,sys
 #importing argv and exit modules

def start(): #defining different functions at the very start
    next = raw_input("> ")
    if next.lower() == "start":
        entrance()
    else:
        print "I'm sorry, I don't understand this command"
start()
def clear_screen(): #will help clear the screen
    os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')

def title(): #A simple title screen
    print "CAVE OF SECRETS"

def battery(): #A simple function to monitor battery life
    LIFE = 10

def dead(reason): #Death messages
    print "You are dead because", reason
    exit(0)
###############################################
#The 'Actual' Game begins here, in the entrance!!
def entrance():
    print "You wake up in a dark cave. There isn't enough light to see anything."
    print "Would you like to move forward anyway?"
    next = raw_input("> ")

    if next.lower() == "yes":
        print "Your feet touch something upon the floor"
        print "\nA FLASHLIGHT! And it still has full battery!"
    elif next.lower() == "no":
        print "So you just stand there....for days. And without any light or way back."
        print "It was only a matter of time before you starved to death anyway. So you convince yourself to give up."
        print "I guess that's easier then actually trying right?"
        print "\nGAME OVER"
        exit(0)
    else: #THIS IS THE ONE GIVING ME ERRORS
        print "I'm sorry, I don't understand this command"
        entrance()
###############################################
clear_screen()
title()
battery()
print "Welcome to the Cave of Secrets"
print "What is your name Adventurer?"
player_name = raw_input("> ")

print "Beware this journey is not for the faint of heart, %s" % player_name
print "Please type in START to begin the quest!"
start()
```

This is my error message when I try and run it in the terminal:

```
File "cave.py", line 43
    else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You need to indent the body of the `entrance` function.

Comment: @edwinksl If that were the case, the error would be on line 2, not at the `else`.

Comment: I copied the code and ran it successfully on my computer with Python2.7 (after indenting the body of `entrance`).  You should be more explicit with what your error is by adding the traceback as part of the question.

Comment: @SethMMorton Running the code as given does indeed give an error on line 2 but the OP claims the `else` statement gives an error. The whole question is inconsistent.

Comment: @edwinksl Which is why I asked for the traceback.  Right now you are assuming the OP pasted the code properly, which may not be true. Any answer without further information from the OP is just a guess as to the real issue.

Comment: indenting entrance() did not work for me.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. You're mixing tabs with spaces. In Python 2, tab corresponds to 8 spaces, not 4. Also, as you're newcomer writing new code, you should switch to Python 3 already.

Comment: You get that syntax error from `else:` line if it is indented at the exactly same level as `def`, because `def` cannot have an `else`. Thus the code in your question doesn't match your real code; the code in question works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely **mixing tabs with spaces** now that you have edited the question the indention *looks* correct and it indeed works as intended with what you have posted.

So the only other thing is your actual file you are executing has mixed tabs and spaces so the indention is incorrect. A good IDE like PyCharm will show you this and warn you about it.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```python
from sys import argv
from sys import exit
from time import *
from random import *
import os,sys
 #importing argv and exit modules

#The 'Actual' Game begins here, in the entrance!!
def entrance():
    print "You wake up in a dark cave. There isn't enough light to see anything."
    print "Would you like to move forward anyway?"
    next = raw_input("> ")

    if next.lower() == "yes":
        print "Your feet touch something upon the floor"
        print "\nA FLASHLIGHT! And it still has full battery!"
    elif next.lower() == "no":
        print "So you just stand there....for days. And without any light or way back."
        print "It was only a matter of time before you starved to death anyway. So you convince yourself to give up."
        print "I guess that's easier then actually trying right?"
        print "\nGAME OVER"
        exit(0)
    else: #THIS IS THE ONE GIVING ME ERRORS
        print "I'm sorry, I don't understand this command"
        entrance()

###############################################     
def start(): #defining different functions at the very start
    next = raw_input("> ")
    if next.lower() == "start":
        entrance()
    else:
        print "I'm sorry, I don't understand this command"
start()
def clear_screen(): #will help clear the screen
    os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')

def title(): #A simple title screen
    print "CAVE OF SECRETS"

def battery(): #A simple function to monitor battery life
    LIFE = 10

def dead(reason): #Death messages
    print "You are dead because", reason
    exit(0)

###############################################
clear_screen()
title()
battery()
print "Welcome to the Cave of Secrets"
print "What is your name Adventurer?"
player_name = raw_input("> ")

print "Beware this journey is not for the faint of heart, %s" % player_name
print "Please type in START to begin the quest!"
start()
```